# Is there something like optional chaining for assignment in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, syntax

Optional chaining is a powerful feature when it comes to access data like

```
const options = cache.[server]?.[channel]?.[service]
```

Now when writing data we generally need to do something like

```
cache[server] ??=  {}
cache[server][channel] ??= {}
cache[server][channel][service] = options
```

Is there something like optional chaining that make assignment like this lighter (maybe in one line)?

Something like :

```
cache[server]??{}:[channel]??{}:[service]=options
```

In this case adding `{}` or `[]` just after would permit to indicate what's expected to assign if nullish.

---

As proposed by @Bergi, the nearest way of doing this is to write like that:

```
((cache[server] ??= {})[channel] ??= {})[service] = options
```

Comment: There is in Coffeescript

Comment: `cache[server]??{}:[channel]??{}:[service]=options` - and this is what I call a readable, clean code

Comment: @kinduser The syntax could be improved, but it would still be better than a series of `if` statements that create all the intermediate objects.

Comment: @Justinas how is it called in Coffescript ?

Comment: @RolandStarke Can you show me an example ?

Comment: I've just tried lodash merge and in some way if we only use objects, it's good, but as soon as we use arrays, it replace them in place in order

Comment: @y.petremann Existential Operator

Comment: As I've seen, Existential operator does permit to chain at assignement, but if one is missing, instead of creating them, it stops and then it's unassigned, I think it can be powerfull too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parenthesis to transform the

```
cache[server] ??= {}
cache[server][channel] ??= {}
cache[server][channel][service] = options
```

into a single expression

```
((cache[server] ??= {})[channel] ??= {})[service] = options
```

Comment: While it's not syntaxic sugar, it's the most modular way of doing what I asked